# Python taking sum and updating for multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x

My input data excel
[image]

I have read into a dataframe
Now in the same dataframe I need to add a new column called aggregate column, For each row that will have the sum  of the amount columns corresponding to the category.
Expected Output with new column aggregate
[image]
For example here for category cat1, there are two rows..sum of amounts in the rows is 15 . So 15 needs to get populated in the aggregate column in the two rows.

Comment: What format is your input data in?  What format do you want the output in?  Do you want it saved as file; displayed on the screen?  What have you tried?  What other info can you give us to help you here?

Comment: Please find my edits on my question

Comment: Below is the code I tried.. FinalData['aggregate']=FinalData.loc[FinalData['category'] == 'cat1', 'Amount'].sum()

Comment: The code works properly fine for category cat1 rows, but as the category column is dynamic as it comes from excel according to category sum should get updated. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a method to solve the same:: Final data is the dataframe name 
FinalData['aggregate']=FinalData.groupby('category')["amount"].transform('sum')